# c# word footer Page and Text

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, footer

I am using word interop to access word files. I am trying to add footer with page numbering on the right side and text on the left. I cant put both on the footer. Any suggestions?

```
foreach (Word.Section wS in mainAction.Sections) {
                        Word.Range footerRange = wS.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                        footerRange.Font.Size = 9;
                        footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
                       
                        footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                        footerRange.Text = "ASDF";
                    }
```

Comment: I have no idea how to write the code for this, but personally, if I were actually using the Word program, I'd add a "right-aligned tab stop" and then tab over to it at the end of the left-aligned text.

Comment: You could insert a table with 1 row and 2 columns and set the required alignment for each of the 2 cells.